# How to do this laravel subquery

Tags: laravel, orm, subquery, left-join, laravel-8

How can I make this query in Laravel:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * from subscribers where subscribers.post_id=2) 
    as sub ON sub.university_id = universities.id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i get that from [sql to laravel query builder converter online](https://sql-to-laravel-builder.herokuapp.com/)

```
DB::table('posts')
->leftJoin('(SELECT * from subscribers where subscribers.post_id=2) as 
sub','sub.university_id','=','universities.id')
->get();
```